# jQuery Not Triggering Span Click on Appended Element

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have a condition within my js file where a file upload triggers my jQuery to append the following element for each returned value, but I am having trouble my click trigger on the delete span tag associated with the link. I am seeing the hash appear in the url indicating a click on the element, but my `console.log` does not fire, indicating to me that something is off.

**Here is my post-image upload jQuery:**

```
$("#file-input").on('change', function(){
        var files = $(this).get(0).files;

        if (files.length > 0){
            var formData = new FormData();

            for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
                var file = files[i];
                console.log(files[i]);
                formData.append('fileUpload', file, file.name);
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: '/app/sign',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(data){
                    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                        console.log('This is the element ' + data[i]);
                        $('.file-preview').append("<a href='" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</a><a href='#' class='remove-file' data-file-link='" + data[i] + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></a><br>");
                    }
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log('error ' + JSON.stringify(error));
                }
            });
        }
        if (files.length > 5){
            alert('You can only upload a maximum of five files at this time');
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**With an emphasis on the appended HTML:**

```
$('.file-preview').append("<a href='" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</a><a href='#' class='remove-file' data-file-link='" + data[i] + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></a><br>");
```

**On `.remove-file` click, I'm not seeing the `console.log` or `alert`:**

```
$('.remove-file').on('click', function(){
    console.log('Delete Triggered');
    var fileLink = $(this).data('file-link');
    alert(fileLink);
    /*alert($(this).attr('href'));
    $.ajax({
        url: '/app/sign',
        type: 'DELETE',
        data: fileLink,
        success: function(){
            $('.file-preview').remove();
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log('error ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    })*/
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click','.remove-file', function(){
```

Try This